# (In app purchase) there is no add duration button on non-renewing subscription item, how can I set it up?

Tags: iphone, ios

I can choose duration of auto renewing subscription since itunes connect already provides

add duration button. but there is no add duration button on non-renewing subscription

so I can't set up the duration of non-renewing subscrition. how do I setup non-renewing

subscription??

Answer (score 3):

You should maintain duration of non-renewing subscription by creating your own server. Let server decide whenever subscription is expired. Ask me if you have more questions about non-renewing subscription